# Can I use fd redirection in bash to input from and output to different files?

Tags: bash, file-descriptor

My program read and write `fd = 3` (for example), I want it read from `file1` and write to `file2` when running it in bash. Can I use fd redirection to make it?

Something like below, but it's wrong

```
./prog 3<file1 3>file2
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to copy file1 to file2 and file1 is a text file:
First open file1 to read from it

`exec 3<file1`

Then file2 to write to it. Use different fd than the one used for file1

`exec 4>file2`

Finally you'd like to iterate over file1 like this

```
while read -u 3 line;  do  echo $line >&4 ; done
```

In fact it can be executed in a single line

```
 exec 3<file1 ; exec 4>file2 ; while read -u 3 line;  do  echo $line >&4 ; done
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks. However, my program read and write the same fd. I think I need to pass a socket-like fd to my program. In fact, I have implemented it using subprocess of python. I just wonder can bash script do it.